# MySQL to PostgreSQL's to_tsvector, @@ and to_tsquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, full-text-search

In PostgreSQL, we can search table based on full text search like this -

```
SELECT title
FROM pgweb
WHERE to_tsvector('english', body) @@ to_tsquery('english', 'friend');
```

Source - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-tables.html

How can we do similar search in MySQL 5.5 which is quite easily done in PostgreSQL?

Comment: thanks @Craig, edited the post with version.. i am working on MySQL 5.5 and all database is in InnoDB. So FTS can substitute above.

Comment: The docs say that MySQL's fulltext search only supports MyISAM until 5.6, so you might be out of luck unless it's supported but undocumented in 5.5 or you have backported support via some "Enterprise" flavour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want MySQL's [full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html) functionality. Essentially you create a `FULLTEXT` index then search against it using [`MATCH() ... AGAINST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match).

I'm not aware of a facility to set the search language per-query in MySQL, but that doesn't mean no such support exists. It wasn't clear if per-query language settings were a requirement for you.

The latest stable release of MySQL supports full text search on the modern transactional and crash-safe InnoDB table type as well as the unsafe MyISAM table type. If your MySQL only does FTS on MyISAM it's time to upgrade. 5.6 supports full text search on InnoDB.

Alternately, if you really can't upgrade, you can store your important data in InnoDB tables and run a periodic query to update a MyISAM table you use as a materialized view for fulltext search only:

- Create a new MyISAM table
- `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` the data from the InnoDB table into the new MyISAM table
- `CREATE` the fulltext index on the new MyISAM table
- `DROP` the old MyISAM table you were using for fulltext indexing; and
- finally [`ALTER TABLE ... RENAME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html) the new MyISAM table to have the name of the old one.

You'll have a very short window during which the fulltext index is unavailable between when you drop the old table and re-create the new one. Your data also gets out of date and stale between view refreshes, though it's possible you can work around that with triggers (I don't use MySQL enough to know). If you can't live with these limitations, upgrade to 5.6.

MySQL's full text search offers control of stopwords and other tuning. It's a solid offering that should do the job nicely.

Comment: (BTW, is there a way to link to the latest MySQL manual? With Pg I link to `/current/` instead of `/9.2/` but there doesn't seem to be an obvious equivalent for MySQL; tried `cur`, `current`, `latest`, `stable` and removing the url component entirely).

Comment: that's a great answer @Craig - I believe MATCH..AGAINST would replace to_tsquery part from query where we add regexp_replace etc..